# Is this form of a matrix diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the identity matrix of order 2, $I_2$. It has the eigen value 1 with algebraic multiplicity = geometric multiplicity = 2. So it can be decomposed in the form $I_2=P^{-1}.B.P$  where $B$ is a diagonal matrix.
And $P$ has columns which correspond to the eigen vectors of $I_2$.

I get the result that eigen vectors corresponding to 1 are of the form $c(1,0)+d(0,1)$ where $c,d \in R$.

So what form does $P$ take?

Comment: Since the matrix $\;I_2\;$ itself is diagonal, we boringly have $\;P=P^{-1}=B=I_2\;$ ...trivial case, and of course: any non-zero vector in $\;\Bbb R^2\;$ is an eigenvector of $\;I_2\;$

Comment: The identity matrix is already diagonal. Why would you want to find (explicitly) $P$? It is the identity matrix itself.

Answer (score 3):

Since the eigenvectors corresponding to $1$ span a $2$-dimensional space, which is also the matrix dimension, $P$ may be any invertible matrix.